# Get the Model ID when i know the name of the model

Tags: function, google-bigquery, documentation, batch-processing, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Im currently trying to run a vertex model on a big query table using python.
I am testing my code which is going to be a custom vertex ai batch exec operator for Airflow.

I can see many functions available with aiplatform lib on google documentation, but i would like to use the model name as a parameter.

For example, in the Model Registry, i have the model named My_Model, which has id 12354795461.
Instead of executing batch directly with the model id, i would like to use the name and get this model id, with a code looking like that :

```
aiplatform.init(project=self.project_id, location=self.location)
my_model = aiplatform.Model()
model_id = my_model.get_model_id(name='My_Model')
model_path = 'projects/'+project_id+'/locations/'+location+'/models/'+model_id
model = aiplatform.Model(model_path)
```

I am using function model.batch_predict with a bigquery table as input.

By the way, i can't find a way to directly ask for the project id as well. I need to give the folder id (parent id), then list all inside, then filter on project_name.

Is there any working function that returns the id of the project/model by using its name as a parameter ?

Second question, is there a way to run a batch prediction on a big query Table and simply eliminate the use of a column in batch prediction ? so we can keep the id of a line without impacting the predictions ?

Thanks very much for your answer,
Regards
Nathan

I tried to add the column id on a BQ table, but the model returned errors because of the id column, when it does not when the id column is not there.

Also i can not find any function on google documentation giving a model/project id directly using the name of the project/model.

Answer (score 0):

I am not that experienced with this but I have a somewhat solution.
So I don't know about getting a project/model id from the name directly but what you can do to get the id is use the google cloud CLI.
I've used the Google Cloud CLI for some projects of my own and I know that after you get your AI model deployed, you can use some CLI functions to get the model ID itself. This would be easy to do as long as you search up a tutorial on how to connect your google account/vertex AI to the CLI. Once your logged in, the CLI should recognize the model registry (AFTER ITS DEPLOYED) and you should be able to grab the information you need!
I know this might not be that helpful but I thought it may be able to help just a little!
Hope it does!
Regards, Sohum.

Comment: Hi Sohum,
Thanks for sharing that with me
I tried to run the CLI commands, and it seems that i CAN get a list of the models with this command : gcloud ai models list --project=project --region=europe-west1

Do you know if it is possible to run the command from a notebook on anaconda or on google colab ? and how to get the list returned ? 

Thanks,
Nathan

Answer (score 0):

This will return a list of models with such a name.

```
model = aiplatform.Model.list(filter=f'display_name="{model_display_name}"')
```

Below will give you an ID

```
id = model[0].name
```

You can use it to instantiate a `Model`

```
model = aiplatform.Model(model_name=id)
```